# How to Center a Button in Bootstrap's Jumbotron?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble centering a button in the bootstrap jumbotron. I have tried using text align center, margin auto 0 px, and other solutions on Stack Overflow. I have my button inside a container which is inside the jumbotron. I don't want to center the container because then the text on the jumbotron would also be centered, which I don't want. I just want the button to be centered.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container" >
        <h2>Keep your heart as if you have just entered this world and your mind as if you have lived it one hundred times.</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center">
           Projects
        </button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS Code

```
.jumbotron {
padding: 20em;
background-image: url("../img/website-background.jpg") !important;
height: 100%; 

/* Center and scale the image nicely */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
}

.jumbotron .container h2 {
color: white;
position: relative;
bottom: 100px;
}
.jumbotron .container button {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `.jumbotron .container` apply `text-align: center;` which will also align the heading in center so target `.jumbotron .container h2` and align it left if you want using `text-align: left;`

OR

Just apply `text-center` class on `container div inside jumbotron` and then target the heading and align its text as left.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h2 class="text-left">Keep your heart as if you have just e it one hundred times.</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Projects</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Omi236/pen/JJVENE?editors=1100

Comment: Your CodePen has negative results. This does not center the button like he asked and he does not want to center the header text.

Comment: @Win Oh my bad, I forgot to save the changes. See again and remove the negative vote :)

Comment: Thanks this works! I still don't understand why applying text-align center to the button didn't work. But whatever works works I guess.

Comment: That didn't work because you were centering the text inside the button by applying the class on button. 
In my example we said center the text inside the div which centers the button which is an inline element.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Kindly vote up my answer as well If you feel appropriate, someone has given me negative vote which is irritating my eyes, I don't know why :(

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it in a div with `text-center` class.

```html
    <div class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container" >
            <h2>Keep your heart as if you have just entered this world and your mind as if you have lived it one hundred times.</h2>
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center">
                 Projects
              </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your button inside a div & apply the following styles on that:

```
.wrapper {
      width: 100px;
      margin: 150px auto;
 }
```

HTML would be like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center">
</div>
```